# Is it possible to write dynamic web pages in Python with the Really Simple HTTP Server?

Tags: python, post, get, webserver, simplehttpserver

I know that with the SimpleHTTPServer I can make my directories accessible by web-browsers via Internet. So, I run just one line of the code and, as a result, another person working on another computer can use his/her browser to see content of my directories.

But I wander if I can make more complicated things. For example, somebody uses his/her browser to load my Python program with a set of parameter (example.py?x=2&y=2) and, as a result, he/she sees the HTML page generated by the Python program (not the Python program).

I also wander if I can process html form submitted to the SimpleHTTPServer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it is possible, you have to do pretty much everything yourself (parsing request parameters, handle routing, etc).

If you are not looking to get experience in creating web-frameworks, but just want to create a small site you should probably use a minimalistic framework instead.

Try Bottle, a simple single-file web framework: http://bottlepy.org

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [VerseMatch](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/tags/_versematch_/) project and related recipes over at ActiveState is something you would be interested in examining? It implements a small application using the standard library for dynamic running.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using CGIHTTPServer instead of SimpleHTTPServer? Then you can toss your scripts in cgi-bin and they'll execute. You have to include content-type header and whatnot but if you're looking for quick and dirty it's real convenient